# Is there a way in excel to calculate the probability of a number occurring?

Tags: excel

In column B I have a set of around 300 numbers from 1 to 50, occurring randomly.
From this set of values I would like to calculate the probability of let's say number 2 occurring after the number 1.

Is there a way to do this?
Thank you very much for the help.

This might seem like a simple problem but I don't know how to write code so I'm totally lost. I've reviewed and tried many solutions on the Web but I can't find the right answer since I don't know how to properly word the issue.

Comment: The question might be unclear. If you already have 300 numbers in column B, there is no probability, you can just count how many times the number 2 comes after the number 1. If you want to calculate the probability of the sequence {1,2} in 300 random numbers, that doesn't really have anything to do with excel, you would just do the math.

Comment: Perhaps better on Cross Validated.

Comment: You have 1/50 chance to have a 1. After that you have 1/50 chance to have a 2. Therefore you should have 1/50/50=0,0004 (0,04%) chance to get a 2 occurring after a 1. To rephrase it: you have 50 possibility on the first roll and another 50 on the second roll. 50*50 = 2500. Only in 1 of these 2500 cases you'll have a 1 followed by a 2. Therefore 1/2500 = 0.0004 (0.04%). Needless to say: it's the same probability of having any 2 specific numbers appearing one after the other (say 1 and 1 or 23 and 44).

Comment: Now if we expand our focus to all the 300 cells, you will have 50^300 possible combinations. You can imagine all the possible result as a 300 "digit" base 50 number. A winning result need to have the sequence 1-2 just once, so the number of possible winning sequences is equal to 1*50^298+1*50^297+1*50^296+...1*50^0. Once you have this number you can divide it by 50^300 and obtain your chances. Or at least, i guess so. Never took a class on probability